# Create a table in SQL with different SELECT statement for each column

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to create a table in SQL using a different SELECT statement for each column. For instance:

```
Column 1: SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name LIKE '%anna%'
COLUMN 2: SELECT cost FROM Property WHERE cost > 18000
```

and then join those columns based on common attribute:

```
INNER_JOIN Property ON Property.id=Person.id
```

How can I do that?

So far I have tried the following approach and wondering if that's correct.

```
select "Person"."name" as "name",
       "Property"."cost" as cost
from "my_schema"."Person" "Person",
     "my_schema"."Property" "Property"
where "Person"."name" LIKE '%anna%'
and "Property"."cost" > 18000
and "Person"."id"="Property"."id"
```

Is there a difference between these two approaches? Would really appreciate some help

Comment: Yes there is difference. 2nd query will return name LIKE '%anna%' and WHERE cost > 18000 When join condition is met. Where as 1st query will all the values for name LIKE '%anna%' and WHERE cost > 18000.

Comment: 1. Do you really want "create table" as CREATE TABLE statement or you trying to write SELECT statement?  2. Columns are cannot be joined, tables are 3. Are you sure that Property.Id and Person.Id are "common attribute"?

Comment: Thanks @saravanatn. But isn't `where "Person"."id"="Property"."id"` and `INNER_JOIN Property ON Property.id=Person.id` the same thing?

Comment: both are same .But Join is preferable in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    Person.name
    , Property.cost

FROM Person
INNER JOIN Property ON Person.id = Property.id
WHERE Person.name LIKE "%anna%"
    AND Property.cost > 18000
```

Comment: Thank you, @Kopytok. But I am wondering if it is different than the second approach mentioned above in terms of results.

Comment: Is it possible to have another column with different condition on `Person.name` for example `Person.name LIKE "%Jill%"` such that we get three columns with different select conditions each?